# How does Route 53 charge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I bought a domain not from AWS and setted it up using route 53 with amazon. The ec2 instance is just running from 2 days without any server running on it (I'm still working on the coding part) but I setted up route 53. Today in my billing I saw this:

[image]

How does it work? I'm still in free tier so I'm not sure if it was covered or not. Even if it was, how did AWS charged 50 cents for 2 days routing when no one visited my site and nothing was running on the ec2 instance? Can somebody explain?

Comment: Did you add DNS records or setup healthcheck?

Comment: @helloV yes i added the DNS records and configured from both the domain name provider and route 53 and the domain correctly pointed to the ec2 instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely the minimum charge for DNS queries or/and for your hosed zones. If you go to billing dashboard, you will clearly see the itemized charges under `Route53`. I see the following itemized charges in my billing dashboard. Even if your `dig` your DNS, it is considered as a query.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Route53 charge you for creating a Hosted Zone (Which is essential to use Route53 Service) which is not under the free tier category. It seems, you were charged for the Hosted Zone created, which is a monthly recurring charge of $0.5 per month, per hosted zone.

Additionally Route53 charges for data transfer as well and for detailed pricing, check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) link.

Comment: Oh I deleted the hosted zone after seeing the price. I thought i was charged everyday for that.

Comment: No its a monthly charge. Anyway you need it if you are using Route53.

Comment: Any idea when I'll get billed for the domain transfer? Also, right now, the nameservers are still the old one.

Comment: @Ashan, if i delete the hosted zone, will i not get billed any longer?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer Yes. AWS stops billing. But I haven't check whether they prorate and charge for the period it was there within the month.

Answer (score 0):

**Hosted Zones and Records**

$0.50 per hosted zone / month for the first 25 hosted zones
$0.10 per hosted zone / month for additional hosted zones
The monthly hosted zone prices listed above are not prorated for partial months. A hosted zone is charged at the time it's created and on the first day of each subsequent month. **To allow testing, a hosted zone that is deleted within 12 hours of creation is not charged, however, any queries on that hosted zone will still incur charges at the rates below.**

A hosted zone includes 10,000 records. For each record greater than 10,000 per zone, you will be charged $0.0015 per month.

Need more than 500 hosted zones or more than 10,000 records in a hosted zone? Please contact us.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/ on 2024-02-03